# Similar representation of flow using leaflet and its plugins for Polyline

Tags: leaflet, google-maps

Is there any javascript plugin of leaflet that can achieve that which are shown in the link?

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/symbols/polyline-symbols.html

Is it as smooth as shown in the link? I am using Mapbox for the maps and I really hope that there is a leaflet-plugin which gives similar functionality as google-maps' Polyline.

Answer (score 1):

See http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#overlay-animations - if what you need is not in there, it doesn't exist (yet).